# Using .Net Core User Secrets for a Team

Tags: asp.net-core

When I use a UserSecret on a project, a UserSecretId entry is added to the project file. This UserSecretId is a GUID which points to a local folder which is not in source control, so my secrets remain secret :) When I commit my project file and a different team member opens the project, is a folder created with the UserSecretId which was added to the project?

Answer (score 16):

The user secrets will not be created when other users clone or checkout your project. The main usecase of user secrets is to create secrets you don't like to share (Means there is no way to share it automatically). [See also this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2739)

### If usersecrets are used by multiple developers:

- Dev1 creates usersecrets:

```
dotnet user-secrets init
dotnet user-secrets set "Movies:ServiceApiKey" "12345"
```

secrets.json will be created in C:\Users\Dev1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets\**32fb5ba1-4330-43a8-a03b-4868ba51ca11**

- Dev2 checkout/clones the project, and creates his secrets:

```
dotnet user-secrets init
```

Gets the message: "The MSBuild project 'C:\Temp\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1
\ConsoleApp1.csproj' has already been initialized with a UserSecretsId."

```
dotnet user-secrets set "Movies:ServiceApiKey" "12345"
```

secrets.json will be created in C:\Users\Dev2\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets\**32fb5ba1-4330-43a8-a03b-4868ba51ca11**

**So both users will have their secrets accessible thru the same GUID** (all user secrets are stored in one file), so there wont be a problem with the project file.

#### Entry in project file for booth Devs:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>32fb5ba1-4330-43a8-a03b-4868ba51ca11</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did a poor job setting up the question. I'll updated it for clarity.

Comment: I updated the answer. I've the same confusion a year ago about the user secret feature ...

Comment: I know that the user secrets won't be created. I've been pretty clear on that part. My question is will a folder be created with the same secretId name, albeit, empty. So, that when Dev 2 pulls down the project, right-mouse clicks the project and clicks manage secrets, a folder with the UserSecretId is created, it's just created with nothing in it.

Comment: No Dev 2, has to go through the same steps you did, ```dotnet user-secrets init```, ```dotnet user-secrets set foo ...```, plus you need secure place for sensitive data anyway for production

Comment: That is not how I created mine. I used Manage User Secrets on the project in the Solution Explorer.  

Dev 1  

1. Clicks Manage User Secrets on project  
2. IDE updates projects file with a <UserSecretsId>{GUID}</UserSecretsId> entry for reference and then creates secrets.json in C:\Users\adria\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets\{GUID}\  
3. User enters secrets, which are stored in secrets.json, which is not in source control  

If Dev 2 adds a secret, and an additional <UserSecretsId> entry is added to the project, how would the IDE know which one to use?

Comment: dotnet user-secrets init does the same thing as the context menu in Solution Explorer. I've tried it out with two users and updated the answer

Comment: Nice. The key for me here was understanding that there can only be a single GUID for a given project. Good discussion and thanks again :)

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: Also, to add to this If you have common secrets used by multiple projects, you can also manually update the ID to a shared one, allowing each project to share the same secrets without having to update each one.